# Add check constraint regex to Oracle Database

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, check-constraints

I have an application where a code like YYY/YY/YY or YYY.YY.YY is inserted before it was only with "."

So the previous developer add a constraint in the corresponding table that I drop in TEST environment but I want to add a new one

```
ALTER TABLE DEPLOYMENT_ADM.DEPLOYMENT 
  ADD CONSTRAINT deployment_chk_billing 
  CHECK (   BILLING_CODE LIKE '[0-9]{3}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}' 
         OR BILLING_CODE LIKE '[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}');
```

But when I try it I have

```
ORA-02293: cannot validate (DEPLOYMENT_ADM.DEPLOYMENT_CHK_BILLING) - check constraint violated
```

So I don't see where is the error

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `regexp_like()`:

```
ALTER TABLE DEPLOYMENT_ADM.DEPLOYMENT ADD CONSTRAINT deployment_chk_billing
 CHECK (regexp_like(BILLING_CODE, '^[0-9]{3}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}$');
```

EDIT:

I wanted to point out the `LIKE` was not correct with wildcards.  I think the regular expression you want is:

```
ALTER TABLE DEPLOYMENT_ADM.DEPLOYMENT 
  ADD CONSTRAINT deployment_chk_billing 
  CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE(BILLING_CODE, '([0-9]{3}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2})' ) );
```

Or if you don't care if `.` and `/` are in the same value:

```
ALTER TABLE DEPLOYMENT_ADM.DEPLOYMENT 
  ADD CONSTRAINT deployment_chk_billing 
  CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE(BILLING_CODE, '[0-9]{3}[./][0-9]{2}[./][0-9]{2})) );
```

Comment: `(regexp_like(BILLING_CODE, '^[0-9]{3}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}$');` 2 open brackets, one closing bracket

Comment: I test it and have the same error, but I see that regexp_like statement are used for select, insert, update and delete...

Comment: How likely is it that existing data violates the constraint you are trying to add?

Comment: Highly likely, @Stilgar, according to error the OP mentioned in their initial message.

Comment: I drop the constraint to add a new one so I don't see how a constraint can be violated. Also all data in the column are like the regex expression.